# Subquery and aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server

```
id  name    gpa  batch
1   jhon    2    y1
2   sandy   2.8  y2
4   kile    3    y2
5   siya    3.2  y1
```

I want to find the batch which got the maximum average gpa.
so I wrote following code.

```
select max(gpa)
from student
where gpa in (select batch,AVG(gpa)
              from student
              group by batch)
```

I check the sub-query by executing it separately and it works fine.But there is an error in the main query.

Comment: What is the output you're trying to generate?

Comment: You should remove `batch` column from the subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TOP` instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1 batch
FROM student
GROUP BY batch
ORDER BY AVG(gpa) DESC
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/448673)</kbd>

---

Using `MAX`:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT batch, avg_gpa = AVG(gpa)
    FROM student
    GROUP BY batch
) s
WHERE avg_gpa = (
    SELECT MAX(avg_gpa)
    FROM (
        SELECT batch, avg_gpa = AVG(gpa)
        FROM #student
        GROUP BY batch
    ) t
)
```

Comment: I haven't learnt about TOP keyword.Can you please explain it?

Comment: [**This**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a good place to start.

Comment: Is there any posiible way to use max function for this query?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns 2 values and In function in main query is looking for 1 item. I would suggest remove batch from internal query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 batch, avg_gpa = AVG(gpa)
FROM   student
GROUP BY batch
ORDER BY avg_gpa desc
```